# Qual a relação entre JPA e ORM?

Tags: jpa, orm, java

Queria saber a relação entre JPA e ORM pois fiquei na duvida, se ambos ,tratam do mesmo assunto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resumo: **JPA** é uma especificação e ORM é a ferramenta (Hibernate, Entity, etc).

No contexto das aplicações Java, para facilitar o processo de transformação dos dados que trafegam entre as aplicações e os bancos de dados, podemos utilizar algumas ferramentas de persistência como o **Hibernate** ou o **EclipseLink**.

Essas ferramentas funcionam como intermediários entre as aplicações e os bancos de dados, automatizando diversos processos importantes relacionados à persistência dos dados. Elas são chamadas de ferramentas **ORM (Object Relational Mapping)**.

Com o intuito de facilitar a utilização dessas ferramentas e torná-las compatíveis com os outros recursos da plataforma Java, elas são padronizadas pela especificação **Java Persistence API (JPA)**. 

Fonte: [Apostila de Java - Persistência com JPA 2 e Hibernate](http://www.k19.com.br/downloads/apostilas/java/k19-k21-persistencia-com-jpa2-e-hibernate)

Comment: *"ORM é a ferramenta (Hibernate..."* - tá esquisito isso. ORM não é ferramenta mas sim conceito, e Hibernate é a ferramenta que implementa o conceito. Ver a reposta do utluiz.

Comment: Por isso coloquei entre parêntesis para indicar que Hibernate, Entity são uma ferramenta de ORM.

Answer (score 8):

A **API de Persistência do Java** (JPA - *Java Persistence API*) é uma especificação de como o **Mapeamento Objeto-Relacional** (ORM - *Object-Relational Mapping*) deve ser implementado na plataforma JavaEE.

Portanto:

- ORM é um conceito geral
- JPA define um padrão de ORM, ou seja, como isso deve funcionar em Java na prática
- Hibernate, EclipseLink, Toplink, OpenJPA são implementações do padrão JPA

Comment: Obrigado ! Ajudou um bocado!!